# Why Magento2 set entity_type_id statically at CategorySetup, CustomerSetup

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, catalog, eav

I am trying to create a custom Eav entity in Magento 2.

I have gone through two core eav entity modules in Magento which are Catalog and Customer.

There are a couple of things which I found strange in these two modules.

#### Setup Files

- **[CategorySetup.php :](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Setup/CategorySetup.php#L82)**

> 'entity_type_id' => self::CATEGORY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID

- **[CustomerSetup.php :](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Setup/CustomerSetup.php#L130)**

> 'entity_type_id' =>
> \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER

It seems like Magento sets `entity_type_id` statically here.

**Q1: Why Magento sets `entity_type_id` statically here though it manages dynamically within  `eav_entity_type` table?**

[image: Please see reference image]

**Q2: When are the records in `eav_entity_type` table created?**

**Q3: If  I need to create a custom EAV model, the how should I define `entity_type_id` for that model**

Comment: you should define your own constant same as above 2 class. `entity_type_id` is AUTO_INCREMENT but the purpose to define as constant is  to retrieve it easily. i know you are confuse if you have another eav module  in that case your id may conflict with it but that is the only way. go with id 9 and in case of conflict you need to just change your  constant value.

Comment: Why  go with  9.'`entity_type_id'`  Should be dynamic

Comment: Hello. I got It returns error like : Unknown entity type: VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Mainpage requested error. Do you know it how to solve? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263579/magento-2-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-ro

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer. And logically deduced therefor prone to error.

The `eav_entity_table` is populated at Magento installation. The only way to change existing values in the table si by custom added logic.

They are making the assumption that no one(in their right mind) changes those values. Ergo they extracted the values into constants making the following **assumption**

**No Magento installation will mess with native entity_type_ids of core Magento entities.**

The reason is simple to deduce: **performance**;

You are right in saying that you should treat your custom `entity_type_id` as a dynamic value because there are other extensions that might have added their own custom-entities so there is no guarantee that 9 will always represent your custom entity for example.