# Magento 2 : Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: magento2, error

When I save records, I got this error message.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (report.vendorname_modulename_entity, CONSTRAINT
>   VENDORNAME_MODULENAME_ENTT_ENTT_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTT_TYPE_ENTT_TYPE_ID
>   FOREIGN KEY (entity_type_id) REFERENCES eav_entity_type
>   (entity_type_id) ), query was: INSERT INTO
>   vendorname_modulename_entity (created_at,updated_at) VALUES
>   ('2019-02-26 00:00:00', '2019-02-27 05:12:31')

**Save controller file (execute function):**

```
$storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store_id', 0);
$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

/** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
if ($data) {
    $params = [];
    $model = $this->modelFactory->create();
    $params['store'] = $storeId;
    if (empty($data['entity_id'])) {
        $data['entity_id'] = null;
    } else {
        $model->load($data['entity_id']);
        $params['entity_id'] = $data['entity_id'];
    }
    $model->setData('entity_type_id', 10);
    $model->setData('attribute_set_id', 17);
    $model->setData('store_id', $storeId);
    $model->setData('field_title', $data['field_title']);
    $model->setData('field_url', $data['field_url']);
    $model->setData('field_desc', $data['field_desc']);
    $model->setData('created_at', $this->_dateFactory->create()->date());
    $model->setData('updated_at', $this->_dateFactory->create()->date());

    try {
        $model->save();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved this record.'));
        $this->_getSession()->setFormData(false);
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
            $params['entity_id'] = $model->getId();
            $params['_current'] = true;
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', $params);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the record.'));
    }

    $this->_getSession()->setFormData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', $params);
}
return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
```

How I solve this error?

Comment: What's the content of your `eav_entity_type` table? Did you add an entity_type for you custom vendorname_modulename_entity? And does this has the id = 10?

Comment: Yes. Right. I add entity_type for my module and yes it's id 10 when I generate.

Comment: OK, what's strange is the stament which throws the error: it is an insert statement with only two values 'created_at' and 'updated_at' and the values are different. Such a statement is imposibile imho with your code since created_at and updated_at have identical values. Is there some magic interferring in your model what can manipulate your statement before saving?

Comment: It returns error like : Unknown entity type: VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Mainpage requested

Comment: Can you please tell me how to solve it?

Comment: please update the question with code of your model, modelfactory and the complete controller constructor and I will look at that

Comment: It's too much long file :( I can't able to post here. Can you please tell me this error why generated? So, I can debug or find it.

Answer (score 1):

Without the specific code it is a little hard to guess but "unknown entity type" could be because of missing value for the entity type in the resource model you have created or a incomplete / incorrect settings in `di.xml`

Resource model needs the entity type set - something like this usually in constructor (you checked that, it's there in your case): `$this->setType('your_entity_type_code');`

"Unknown entity type: VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Mainpage requested" comes from the getMetadata() method in the EntityManagers MetadataPool. The `di.xml` needs a tag for `Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool` to avoid this error

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool">
  [....]
  <item name="eavEntityType" xsi:type="string">your_entity_type_code</item>
```

If the `di.xml` is correct and you have generated the dependency injection after the changes, we have to look further :-)

Comment: Yes. I added this line in ResourceModel file : $this->setType(Mainpage::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE); & ENTITY_TYPE_CODE = entity_type_code

Comment: I have updated the answer because it's easier to read than in comments

Comment: In my di.xml there are no any MetadataPool type tag. Is it required? Because, I don't need to API in my module so.

Comment: Sorry. But, I'm new in create eav entity type module.

Comment: "Unknown entity type: VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Mainpage requested" comes from the `getMetadata()` method in the EntityManagers MetadataPool, that's all I can guess from what you have posted - I don't know anything about your code. So try to debug where the calls come from, it doesn't make sense to spend a lot of time trying to guess your code :-)

Comment: Check this answer it might be your problem too. Please check that your resource model is build that way: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263965/magento-2-foreing-key-constraint-issue/263995#263995