# Magento 2 : Foreing key constraint issue

Tags: magento2, error, install-script

I'm trying to save records using the controller. I set foreign key in `attribute_set_id` and `entity_type_id` field in main table with `eav_attribute_set` and `eav_entity_type` respectivelly.

But, when I save records it can't save.

**Controller code :**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $moduleNameFactory;
    protected $_dateFactory;
    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory resultPageFactory
    * @param \VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ModuleNameFactory $moduleNameFactory
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ModuleNameFactory $moduleNameFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTimeFactory $dateFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->moduleNameFactory = $moduleNameFactory;
        $this->_dateFactory = $dateFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
    * @return void
    */
    public function execute()
    {
        $module = $this->moduleNameFactory->create();
        $module->setEntityTypeId(15); // this value can't saved in main table
        $module->setAttributeSetId(22); // this value can't saved in main table
        $module->setTitle('Title');
        $module->setUrl('url');
        $module->setDesc('desc');
        $module->setStatus(1);
        $module->setCreatedAt($this->_dateFactory->create()->date());
        $module->setUpdatedAt($this->_dateFactory->create()->date());
        $module->save();
    }
}
?>
```

**InstallSchema.php :(entity_type_id & attribute_set_id code)**

```
$table->addColumn(
            'entity_type_id',
            Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            [
                'unsigned' => true,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => '0',
            ],
            'Entity Type ID'
        )->addIndex(
            $setup->getIdxName($tableName, ['entity_type_id']),
            ['entity_type_id']
        )->addForeignKey(
            $setup->getFkName(
                'vendorname_modulename_entity',
                'entity_type_id',
                'eav_entity_type',
                'entity_type_id'
            ),
            'entity_type_id',
            $setup->getTable('eav_entity_type'),
            'entity_type_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        );

        $table->addColumn(
            'attribute_set_id',
            Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            [
                'unsigned' => true,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => '0',
            ],
            'Attribute Set ID'
        )->addIndex(
            $setup->getIdxName($tableName, ['attribute_set_id']),
            ['attribute_set_id']
        )->addForeignKey(
            $setup->getFkName(
                'vendorname_modulename_entity',
                'attribute_set_id',
                'eav_attribute_set',
                'attribute_set_id'
            ),
            'attribute_set_id',
            $setup->getTable('eav_attribute_set'),
            'attribute_set_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        );
```

It returns error when save :

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`m226`.`vendorname_modulename_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_5F02A602AEE613FE515E787AA9C5EB1F` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `vendorname_modulename_entity` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2019-03-01 06:04:57', '2019-03-01 06:04:57')"

If, I set default value null in both field then, error not return but field always set null value.

How to solve it?

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can see in the error message, the insert is not correct as there are only two columns in the statement and that is obvious wrong: `INSERT INTO vendorname_modulename_entity (created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('2019-03-01 06:04:57', '2019-03-01 06:04:57')`.

The problem might be in your model or resource model:
Did you define a method `setEntityTypeId` in your model which sets the entity tyo or type id in resource model? 
If not your method can't do what you expect. The easiest way imho is to set the entity type directly in your resource model since it is fixed. In this way you don't need to set it for every entity.

Add a function like this in your resource model:

```
public function getEntityType() {
    if(empty($this->_type)) {
        $this->setType('your_entity_type_code_here');
    }

    return parent::getEntityType();
}
```

After debugging the code together in the chat, the solution was to build the resource model only with the above method and `_getDefaultAttributes()` like follows:

```
protected function _getDefaultAttributes()
{
    return ['entity_type_id', 'attribute_set_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

Comment: Did you define a method setEntityTypeId in your model which sets the entity tyo or type id in resource model? : No, Can you please add code here? I added getEntityType() function in resourceModel.

Comment: If you have added getEntityType() function in resourceModel and try to save the model whithout calling $model->setEntityTypeId what happens? Same error?

Comment: Yes. still same. I just temporary change type of entity_type_id default is null. So, It's save NULL instead of entity_type_id.

Comment: In the `AbstractEntity` the value of `entity_typ_id`  is taken from your `getEntityType` method like this: `$this->getEntityType()->getEntityTypeId()` so usually there is no need to set it. I guess there is something else wrong with your eav entity model or resource model. I would try to debug somewhere in a method like `_beforeSave()`.  Do you have a stacktrace from your exception?

Comment: Where should add this method _beforeSave()?

Comment: in your resource model which should inherit from `AbstractEntity`. If that's not enough you can just copy the `save()` method from `AbstractEntity` in your resource model and add some more debug information the the different steps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90427/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and-helgeb).

Comment: It returns : Unknown entity type: VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ModuleName requested. Can you please check chat room?